# Fill column value from value above until it hits new value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, automation, sql-update

Currently, I have a table that has values filled in like this:

[image: Current Table]

I need to add a trigger that will fill in the values on insert, so the end result looks like this:

[image: End Goal]

The process is similar in excel where you drag down the value. But I need it to stop before it hits a new value, and start the process over again.

However, sometimes there may not be a next value. How would I stop the update if there is no end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two correlated subqueries.

```
create table #YourTable (RowNumber int identity(1,1), [Value] int null)
insert into #YourTable 
values
(10),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(20),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(30),
(null),
(40),
(null),
(null),
(50)


select 
    t.RowNumber
    ,OldVal =   t.Value
    ,NewVal =   case 
                    when t.[Value] is null 
                        then (select t3.[Value] 
                              from #YourTable t3 
                              where t3.RowNumber = (select max(RowNumber) 
                                                    from #YourTable t2 
                                                    where t2.RowNumber < t.RowNumber and t2.Value is not null)
                             ) 
                    else [Value] 
                end
from #YourTable t
order by
    t.RowNumber

drop table #YourTable
```

If you are looking to update the table, here is how you would do that (new test data).

```
create table #YourTable (RowNumber int identity(1,1), [Value] int null)
insert into #YourTable 
values
(10),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(5),
(null),
(null),
(null),
(20),
(null),
(15),
(null),
(null),
(30),
(null),
(40),
(null),
(null),
(50),
(null),
(null)

update t
set  [Value] =  case 
                    when t.[Value] is null 
                        then (select t3.[Value] 
                              from #YourTable t3 
                              where t3.RowNumber = (select max(RowNumber) 
                                                    from #YourTable t2 
                                                    where t2.RowNumber < t.RowNumber and t2.Value is not null)
                             ) 
                    else [Value] 
                end
from #YourTable t


select * from #YourTable order by RowNumber
```

Once you have the table updated, then your insert statement just needs to check if the value you are inserting `IS NULL` or not, and if it is, set it to the last value. That would be like this...

Here we insert a `NULL` thus the inserted value will actually be 50 based off the last test table

```
declare @valToInsert int = null
insert into #YourTable
select case when @valToInsert is null then (select top 1 [Value] from #YourTable order by RowNumber desc) else @valToInsert end
```

Then, since we aren't inserting a `NULL` below, it will insert the actual value

```
declare @valToInsert int = 14
insert into #YourTable
select case when @valToInsert is null then (select top 1 [Value] from #YourTable order by RowNumber desc) else @valToInsert end
```

Comment: Your answer got me halfway there. I tried to implement your code but I found it would overwrite some null values with incorrect data.I need to be sure these null values are correct 100% of the time.

Comment: You just made up a totally different value for the first column. What's the ACTUAL data for this column? What determines a "set" as you described in your edit? The first letter of the row? etc... you need to be specific. The original answer was perfect for the original question.

Comment: I apologize. I do have an incremental value, but that proves unreliable. However I also have sub incremental values on each import. Basically takes the filename and adds an incremental value to it. I was wondering if i could do a similar operation using that instead.

Comment: I could @AlanPear. Since you closed this question, can you open another with the actual data sample?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for your help